# execute a php file on selection of dropdown value

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

i have been searching a solution for days and i have tried ajax/jquery methods posted online but it just wouldnt work. I have a drop down list which gets its value from the database. On selecting any value apart from "Select", i want to display a value which is called upon by a php file:

here's my code for the form:

```
         <tr>  
        <fieldset id="Date">
          <td class="select"><label><span class="text_9">Date:</span></label></td>
          <td><select name="date" id="date">
          <option value="">Select</option>
          <?php include_once "selectdate.php"?></td>
          </select>
     </tr>
        </fieldset>
   </table>
```

and here's the php to run on selection of the drop down (called retrieve.php)

```
<?php
include_once "connect.php";
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password); 

$form=$_GET;
$trade=$form['tradetype'];
$metal=$form['metal'];
$amount=$form['amount'];
$date=$form['date'];

$stmt = $conn->query("SELECT Discount FROM Contracts WHERE Trade='$trade' AND Metal='$metal' AND Amount='$amount' AND ExpiryDate='$date'");
while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) { 
   echo ($row['Discount']); 
} 
?>
```

As you can see, the php to be run uses the value from multiple form elements...

I am very new to jquery/ajax... any help is appreciated as i want the result to be displayed on the same page as the form is. Thank you!

Comment: Where are you sending ajax? What is `$form`? You are open to SQL injections with this code. Use parameterized prepared statements. http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php

Comment: The `tr` and `fieldset` open and close tags do not match. Just FYI.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get data from another file to a `select`, you should add as option. Plain text inside `select` will not help you out. So wrap the vales with `<option></option>`

So change this line,

```
echo "<option>{$row['Discount']}</option>";
```

If you want to give values,

```
 echo "<option value='{$row['Discount']}'>{$row['Discount']}</option>";
```

**EDIT**

Now onchange of deopdown, `date` call ajax to do next stuff.

```
$(document).on("change","#date",function() {
     var tradetype = //capture the value here;
     var metal = //capture the value here;
     var amount = //capture the value here;
     $.ajax({
          url:"path/filename.php",
          data:{date:$(this).val(),"tradetype":tradetype,"metal":metal,"amount":amount},
          type: "POST",
          success: function(data){
               alert(data);//this will alert what you have echoed on php file
          }
     });

});
```

Comment: Need to give it a value as well.

Comment: He has included a file and echoed the values from db inside `select`. He is just echoing the value in php file. He shud wrap with `<option>` tag.

Comment: I was about to add that in answer. But you asked for clarification.

Comment: Yea, answer was very vague to begin with. OP still has multiple issues with the current approach.

Comment: Yes, i will try changing my answer.

Comment: hi! sorry i think i was unable to explain myself well! the php above is not for the dropdown option selection but rather something to run after the date option is selected. I am able to get the data for the dropdown options already. that is a different php (selectdate.php is separate from the above php code)

Comment: so on change of current dropdown, you want to fetch something else??

Comment: the alert does not echo the php answer...there is just a blank in the alert

Comment: what have you echoed in the php file?? please add that code in question as well.

Comment: it is there in my question above (under the php code (retrieve.php)

Comment: you have 4 values to be sent. so send all 4 in ajax.

Comment: umm sry i am new to ajax --> how do i send 4 value?

Comment: you have to capture the values from textbox/ select before you send it.. Check the answer,

Comment: the type should be GET right since i am getting a data in my php?

Comment: Ya... I didn't see that ur using get... Please change get to post in Ajax...  Or use post in php...

Comment: still getting a blank... tried different syntax also doesnt work for the data

Comment: Is there any error in console?? also add `print_r($_POST);` in your php file and see what its printing.